# Android code - any way to override text input box to lowercase?

Tags: android

I have a specific situation, I'm using EditTextPreference in preferences to allow user to input word/name for a preference. When app opens text input box I need it to be in lowercase, it seems default is in uppercase for first letter.

```
<EditTextPreference
        android:title="Your Name"
        android:key="yname"
        android:capitalize="none" <-- DOES NOT WORK..
        android:summary="name:"
        android:defaultValue="george"
         >
    </EditTextPreference>
```

When this app uses preferences code and user selects item it opens text input box with caps lock on first letter... urgh! lol !

Can I simply use an @Override on the default use of uppercase for first letter in the input text box?

Comment: Do you want to limit it to only lower-case letter (no numbers or punctuation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems `android:inputType="text"` should clear all capitalization flags:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

Comment: Great! the "text" to my surpise did not clear cap, but i used "textUri", "textVisiblePassword", "textEmaiLAddress"... also tried for fun others. Very sweet! Thank you a TON. =]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the folowing in your preferences class.

```
  public class TaskPreferences extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.task_preferences);

      EditTextPreference xx = (EditTextPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.your_pref_key));;
      xx.getEditText().setKeyListener(TextKeyListener.getInstance(false, TextKeyListener.Capitalize.NONE));
    }
}
```